# Fokker-Planck equation for joint probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

Given a two-dimensional Ito stochastic equations
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{d} x &= \mu_1(x,y) \mathrm{d} t + \sigma_{11}(x,y) \mathrm{d} W_1 + \sigma_{12}(x,y) \mathrm{d} W_2, \\
    \mathrm{d} y &= \mu_2(x,y) \mathrm{d} t + \sigma_{21}(x,y) \mathrm{d} W_1 + \sigma_{22}(x,y) \mathrm{d} W_2,
\end{align}
would it be possible to derive two Fokker-Planck equations for marginal probability density functions $p(x)$ and $p(y)$, instead of the joint probability $p(x,y)$?

Thanking you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the corresponding PDE for marginal probability distribution does not exist because the processes x(t) and y(t) are not Markovian anymore.